# Why always get the blank data on onMessageReceived() method in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to implement the push notification. The push is coming fine. The message is showing on the status bar but the `onMessageRecieved()` I am getting the the blank array. So far I am using:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());


    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String value1 = data.get("key1");
    String value2 = data.get("key2");

}
```

Comment: What is the content of data when you use the following log:
`Log.e(TAG, "data: " + remoteMessage.getData());`?

Comment: please post the payload which you are sending in firebase api.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. msg is a string variable

```
     if (remoteMessage.getData() != null && remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("remoteMessage. Data():" + remoteMessage.getData());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            msg = data.get("body");

        } else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            System.out.println("remoteMessage.Display():" + remoteMessage.getData());
            msg = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }
```